# MUJOCO_PY:Computed torque control for kuka iiwa14 robot

Tags: python, numpy, controls, robotics, mujoco

I'm new with mujoco_py.I already installed it successfully on linux and I have the URDF file of the robot(kukaiiwa14) but I don't know how can I manipulate the joints.For example I want to know the commands of how can I apply a force on a joint .
I have to apply optimal control on this robot so that he throws a ball for a specific distance  if someone has an idea about it please help.
If someone could help me by this Project I would be so grateful.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`mujoco_py` is unsupported and deprecated, you should probably use MuJoCo's [native Python bindings](https://mujoco.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python.html).

Regarding applying forces to joints, the actuation model is described [here](https://mujoco.readthedocs.io/en/latest/computation.html#actuation-model), and you can find various examples, e.g. [here](https://github.com/deepmind/mujoco/blob/main/model/humanoid/humanoid.xml#L142) that might help you along.

Comment: I have another question I wanted to add actuators on urdf file of a robot but this code is ignored:<actuator><motor joint="iiwa_joint_1" name="torque1" gear="1" ctrllimited="true" ctrlrange="-100 100" /><position name="pservo1" joint="iiwa_joint_1" kp="10"/><velocity name="vservo1" joint="iiwa_joint_1" kv="5"/></actuator> so how can I add actuators on an urdf file and what's the equivalent of <actuator> </actuator>

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know URDF does not support actuators. I recommend that you import the URDF, [save](https://mujoco.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modeling.html#saving-models) the resulting MJCF, and then edit the MJCF directly.

[This](https://mujoco.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modeling.html#urdf-extensions) might be relevant.

Comment: Thanks for your advice but I couldn't save the resulting MJCF I m using mujoco_py and this is my code could you please give me the command for saving it:
[from mujoco_py import load_model_from_path, MjSim, MjViewer
import os
from mujoco_py import functions
import numpy as np
model = load_model_from_path("/home/aymen/.mujoco/mujoco210/kuka14/kukaIiwa14.xml")
#kukaIiwa14.xml is an urdf file but I only changed .urdf to .xml#
sim = MjSim(model) ]
Because I ve tried mj_saveModel/sim.save(model ) and it didn't work